# Use :simple_one_to_one to start dynamical supervisors

Tags: elixir

Is it possible in Elixir to start supervisors dynamically using :simple_one_to_one strategy, using Supervisor.start_child, or it's limited for GenServer workers ? If yes, let me ask you an example,
many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Supervisors don't care if their children are workers or other supervisors. There is an example of using `:simple_one_for_one` strategy on the [elixir lang page](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html).

The only difference is that in the child specification instead of:

```
worker(KV.Bucket, [], restart: :temporary)
```

You would use something like:

```
supervisor(KV.Bucket.Supervisor, [])
```